# create checkbox inside uitableviewcell

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uitableview

I have uitaleviewcell with different sections and rows, I want to have checkbox cell that you can see in the picture

my question is how can I create checkbox in uitableviewcells?(I used storyboard)

[image]

Comment: refer this "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11859357/adding-check-box-to-one-of-sections-in-uitableview"

Answer (score 0):

Use `UISwitch` and in the property inspector, set an empty box image for normal state and a checked box image for highlighted state. However checkbox behaviour is represented by switches in ios, a checkbox has a very small hit area and might pose a usabilty problem for your users, especially when they are close to each other as in the image you provided.

[UISwitch Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISwitch_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 0):

Each checkbox cell should be a *Custom* TableViewCell. Then simply drop an ImageView and a Label in the TableViewCell and use didSelectRowAtIndex: to toggle the image between checked/unchecked.

Comment: But how can I specify sections and rows

Comment: You said you are using storyboards.  Create all the cells you want in the desired sections.  Then go to the first cell you want to be a checkbox.  Change it to a Custom cell in the Properties editor.  Then drag a image and label component into it.  You can give the cell unique ID's in the Properties editor so you can reference them in code.

Comment: To be clear, each checkbox will be its own UITableViewCell.  The sections will come from the UITableView.

Answer (score 0):

You need two images for imageView of cell

```
#define SELECTED_ROW @"selectedRowImage.png" // CheckBox with Selected sign png
#define NOT_SELECTED_ROW @"notSelectedRowImage.png" // Empty CheckBox png

      // listSelected is array of indexes selected

in ViewDidLoad:

NSMutableArray *listSelected = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

// CellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {   

    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"select";    
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: cellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier] autorelease];

        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    }

   if ([self checkIfIndexPathAlreadySelected:indexPath])
            cell.tag = 1;
        else cell.tag = 0;

    if(cell.tag == 0)
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:NOT_SELECTED_ROW]; 
    else
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:SELECTED_ROW];   

    return cell;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {     

     UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];     
     if(cell.tag == 0)
     {
         cell.tag = 1;
         [self.listSelected addObject:indexPath]];
         cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:SELECTED_ROW];        
     }
     else if(cell.tag == 1)
     {
         cell.tag = 0;
         [self.medicineIndexArray removeObject:indexPath];
         cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:NOT_SELECTED_ROW];        
     }
 }


- (BOOL)checkIfIndexPathAlreadySelected:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    if([self.listSelected containsObject:indexPath])
        return YES;
    else 
        return NO;
}
```